# Kernel error at start. How can I fix it?

Tags: boot, startup, bios, error-handling

Everytime I restart or turn on my pc I see those line of error. After like 30 seconds the PC work like ever.

First error

[image: first]

Second
[image]

Can someone help me?

**`For sudo blkid`**

```
`/dev/zram1: UUID="ba0ef524-ba50-4fcd-84fd-8bdf6d7b6fad" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram0: UUID="92c0aabf-61f8-4351-b616-3aa5c9abc55e" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda3: UUID="f3950ee1-e574-42b4-9cf8-d599cda43341" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="df7d6bd4-50f3-481a-83b9-7b9829594c10"
/dev/sda1: UUID="F0C6-C4B7" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="f94b2cb7-7654-48ba-a7ec-02f5b2e99046"
/dev/sda2: UUID="cdc76b7b-9058-4623-8a9f-2eac3839f567" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2b017623-f39d-4eff-960d-3b9a89e6295f"
```

**`Instead for cat /etc/fstab...`**

```
`cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=cdc76b7b-9058-4623-8a9f-2eac3839f567 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=F0C6-C4B7  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=f3950ee1-e574-42b4-9cf8-d599cda43341 none            swap    sw              0       0
`
```

`
**Info for sudo lshw -C video**

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Although I think this is a video-related problem, please edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`... I just want to check out a hunch. Start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them. Let me know when you have edited your question.

Comment: @heynnema Question edited!!

Comment: Thanks! fstab looks fine. blkid indicates 3 swap files, two in zram. Did you install zram-config, or some other zram app? That's got to go. How much RAM do you have? What kind of video controller do you have? ATI/Nvidia? Show me `sudo lshw -C video`.

Comment: @heynnema I did not intsall any app. The card it's an integrated one...I just updated the info into the question.

Comment: Did you install the `Intel Video Driver for Linux`? Please show me `sudo fdisk -l` and `swapon` and `dpkg -l *zswap*` and `dpkg -l intel-microcode`. How much RAM do you have? Does the computer eventually work fine, or does it have other troubles? What version OS? Do you have the most current BIOS installed?

Comment: @heynnema I have 4 GB of Ram and I did not install the intel video driver

sudo fdisk -l -> https://pastebin.com/jZMXbBNk

swapon ->
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda3 partition 3.9G 1.2G   -1

Comment: But Overall the pc seems that is working well

Comment: The version is 16.04 LTS @heynnema

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions, but because of the nature of your problem, I have to get a base feeling about your config. In `Software & Updates`, Updates tab, make sure that the last popup setting is "For any new version", and then run `Software Updater` and update to 16.04.2. Also, I didn't see `dpkg -l *intel* | grep ii`. Lastly, did you check the manufacturer's web site for a BIOS update?

Comment: dpkg -l *intel* | grep ii -> https://pastebin.com/VVYw3Ck6
Bios info -> https://pastebin.com/S8guJc9b
yep I the bios it's updated @heynnema

Comment: Please see my partial answer. Report back.

Comment: Where do we stand?

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

From the comments...

- upgrade from 16.04 to 16.04.2
- (*if you have Intel processors*) install `intel-microcode`
- update the BIOS from 203 to 211 by going to https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/557/0/1/NjTBDAvwQa2EHvsG/41/ (**confirm for yourself** that I've got the correct page for your computer model #)

**Update #1:**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`